# PHP - check if file is archived without using handle resource

Tags: php, curl, php-ziparchive

Is there a way to check if content received from remote server is a .zip archive? I found many solutions here, but all of them are for local files; therefore, these solutions use file handle resources like fopen, fgets, etc.

Put simply, curl is used to get content from remote server. Depending on validation results on remote server (which I don't have access to), it returns a .zip archive OR error message in plain text. If .zip archive is returned, the content I receive from curl looks like:

```
PK
 A‘OCBÇ—= = 
 and many more symbols here....
```

Then I simply use fwrite function to write received content into local file. Naturally, if no archive is returned, content looks like:

```
some random message here
```

This is all I have. So, is there any way to check if returned content is a .zip archive? Sure, I could use a solution like:

```
if (stristr($content, "some random message here")) {//not zip archive}
```

but this is lame...

Comment: If you trust remote server, you can rely on Content-Type header.

Comment: I guess it's impossible to get headers from content I have. I'm asking because I need to use many curl get/post requests, so I'm using such a function - $content=curl_get($url, $params), where $content is content returned by remote server. Otherwise, I guess it will be needed to rewrite some code.

Answer (score 1):

After some more research, I found out zip archives should start with "PK", so I wrote such a code (in case someone has a similar problem in future):

```
if (substr($content, 0, 2) == 'PK' && strlen($content)>100000) {echo "this is zip";}
```

This code is not the greatest choice (because you need to trust remote server), but it's better than nothing. I also added strlen function to verify that returned content is "big enough" (over 100 KB) to be a zip archive.

If someone has a better solution which works without using file handle resource, I'll be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Linux or *BSD server you can do something like this:

```
$result = shell_exec('file cccr_logo.zip');
echo 'result:['.$result.']';
```

Which should spit out something like this:

```
result:[cccr_logo.zip: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract ]
```

If you want to test against a standard `$result`, you can use the `-b` switch like so:

```
$result = shell_exec('file -b cccr_logo.zip');
echo 'result:['.$result.']';
```

And now a valid zip will be (no file name):

```
result:[Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract ]
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the script is also used on Windows machines too.